# Creating two buttons side by side without a break

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view where I want to add two buttons to it where the first goes to the middle of the screen and then the other starts where the other ends.

My code is seen below, which works other than the fact that there is a space between the two buttons which I do not want.

```
var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

var body: some View {
    
    HStack() {
        
        Button(action: {
            
            print("Create Pool")
            
        }) {
            
            Text("Create")
            
        }
        .frame(width: screenWidth/2, height: 200, alignment: .center )
        .background(Color.blue)
        //.padding(0)
    
        Button(action: {
            
            print("Join Pool")
            
        } ) {
            
            Text("Join")
            
        }
        .frame(width: screenWidth/2, height: 200, alignment: .center )
        //.frame(minWidth: screenWidth/2)
        .background(Color.red)
        //.padding(0)
        
    }
    .padding(0)
    
}
```

Can anyone help remove the space, so it truly is a where one button ends the other starts.

Comment: Does `HStack(spacing: 0) {` work?

Comment: Yes it did.. wow thx!!! I was doing padding and everything else except that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add spacing to hstack

```
 HStack(spacing: 0) {
```